# How to reference custom UITableView cell inside another function (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I am trying to achieve functionality similar to Apple's reminders app where a tableview holds all the reminders and a + button at the end adds a new object.

My objects are held in an array called `tempActions`, which is the data source for the tableView.

Pressing 'Add Action' appends a new object to the array with the title "Empty Cell".[image]

The title is a `UITextView` which users will be able to edit, but here's what I can't figure out how to do:

**How do I take the text from the `UITextView` of that particular cell, append it to the array at the correct index (the index corresponds to indexPath.row) and then display it in the cell.label?**

I thought of using the textViewDidEndEditing method but what I don't know how to do is reference the correct cell from the cellForRowAt method.

Would anyone be able to help clarify this, or am I approaching it in the wrong way?

Here's the code for the entire class:

```
class Step3: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate {

// Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var sectionText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sectionHeader: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var teableViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

@IBAction func addAction(_ sender: Any) {

    tempActions.append(Action(title: "Empty Cell", completed: false))

    tableview.reloadData()
    tableview.layoutIfNeeded()
    teableViewHeight.constant = tableview.contentSize.height

    print(tempActions)
}

@IBAction func nextAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let newGoal = Goal(
        title: tempTitle,
        description: tempDescription,
        duration: tempDuration,
        actions: nil,
        completed: false
    )

    newGoal.save()

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToHome", sender: nil)
}


func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tempActions.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ActionCell", for: indexPath) as! ActionCell

    cell.label.text = tempActions[indexPath.row].title
    cell.label.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 12, left: 0, bottom: 12, right: 0);
    cell.label.delegate = self

    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 40
    tableview.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
}

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to click the cell write something then reload and see the text as title?

Comment: @NickStefanidis Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it -- the textView is in a cell, and you want to find that cell in `textViewDidEndEditing`.  If the superview of the textfield is the cell, you could do this:

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if let cell = textView.superview as? ActionCell, 
         let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
      // Now you have the indexPath of the cell
      // update tempActions

           // YOUR CODE HERE

      // Then reloadRows
      tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath]), with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Another thing you could do is make tempAction's type have a unique ID and then store that in the `ActionCell` -- when you want to find the index, look up the ID in the tempActions array to find its index.

Comment: Thank you for this, tableView.indexPath(for: cell) was what I needed. How could I get the text inside the UITextView of that cell though? Normally I'd make an outlet in my Step3 class, but this is a custom cell so the outlet is inside the custom cell's class.

Comment: `textView.text`

Comment: My mistake, I realised the custom cell is not the superview of the textfield, it gets automatically wrapped in a Content View. if let cell = textView.superview?.superview as? ActionCell, worked. Thank you.